# Two-variable limit to (0,0)

Tags: limits

I would like help with calculating the following limit:

$$\text{lim}_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}$$

I tried diffrent things and I always get the limit is 1 but Im not sure this is the answer.

any insight will be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $$x=r\cos (t)\;,\; y=\sin (t) $$

then, the function becomes

$$e^{2r^4\cos^2 (t)\sin^2 (t)\ln (r)} $$

but $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}r\ln (r)=0$$

thus

your limit will be $$e^0=1$$

since

$\sin $ and $\cos $ are bounded.

Comment: Hi,
Wolframs' answer to this limit is 0.
I tried to solve this myself in other ways and also ended up with 1.
Is wolfram wrong about this one?

Comment: wolfram is not a man.